# Is this a case where I need a functor?

Tags: ocaml

I'm using the [Bitstring module](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/bitstring/html/Bitstring.html#VALbitstring_length) in the following code:

```
let build_data_32 v wid =
  let num = wid / 32 in
  let v' = Int32.of_int(v) in
  let rec aux lst vv w = match w with
    0 -> lst
  | _ -> (BITSTRING { vv : 32 } ) :: ( aux lst (Int32.succ vv) (w-1)) in
  Bitstring.concat ( aux [] v' num ) ;;
```

Note that when you have `BITSTRING { vv : 32 }` 
that vv is expected to be an Int32 value.  I'd like to generalize this function to work with different widths of bitstrings; ie, I'd like to create a build_data_n function where the bitstring would be constructied with `BITSTRING { vv : n }` .

However, the problem here is that if n is less than 32 then the succ function used above would just be the succ for type int. If it's greater than 32 it would be Int64.succ  Same issue above in the line `let v' = Int32.of_int(v) in`  - for values less than 32 it would simply be: `let v' = v in` , whereas for values greater than 32 it would be: `let v' = Int64.of_int(v) in`

Is this a case where a functor would come in handy to generalize this function and if so, how would I set that up?  (and if there's some other way to do this that doesn't require functors, that would be nice to know as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `BITSTRING { vv : n }`, i.e. using runtime-specified field length, the type of `vv` cannot depend on `n` as it is not the compile-time constant anymore, so `vv` is forced to `int64`.

Comment: So are you saying that if you use a variable for the field length (n above) that vv will always be forced to be an int64?

Comment: Ah, yes, I see what you're getting at: # let get_bitstring v n = BITSTRING { v : n } ;;
val get_bitstring : int64 -> int -> Bitstring.bitstring = <fun>

Answer (score 4):

There are a few approaches available.  One is to use a functor, similar to the following:

```
(* The signature a module needs to match for use below *)
module type S = sig
  type t
  val succ : t -> t
  val of_int : int -> t
end

(* The functor *)
module Make(M : S) = struct
  (* You could "open M" here if you wanted to save some typing *)
  let build_data v =
    M.succ (M.of_int v)
end

(* Making modules with the functor *)
module Implementation32 = Make(Int32)
module Implementation64 = Make(Int64)

let foo32 = Implementation32.build_data 12
let foo64 = Implementation64.build_data 12
```

Another is to wrap your data type in a record:

```
(* A record to hold the relevant functions *)
type 'a wrapper_t = { x : 'a; succ : 'a -> 'a }

(* Use values of type 'a wrapper_t in *)
let build_data v =
  v.succ v.x

(* Helper function to create 'a wrapper_t values *)
let make_int32_wrapper x = { x = Int32.of_int x; succ = Int32.succ }
let make_int64_wrapper x = { x = Int64.of_int x; succ = Int64.succ }

(* Do something with a wrapped int32 *)
let foo32 = build_data (make_int32_wrapper 12)
let foo64 = build_data (make_int64_wrapper 12)
```

And finally, if you are using OCaml 3.12.0 or later, you can use first class modules:

```
(* You can use the module type S from the first example here *)

let build_data (type s) m x =
  let module M = (val m : S with type t = s) in
  M.succ x

let int32_s = (module Int32 : S with type t = Int32.t)
let int64_s = (module Int64 : S with type t = Int64.t)

let foo32 = build_data int32_s 12l
let foo64 = build_data int64_s 12L
```

Each of these approaches can be mixed and matched.  You may also be able to wrap your values in variant types or objects to get a similar result.

Comment: Quite frankly, I think your solutions are just too complicated for a reply to a potentially-beginner question. I know first-class modules are new, hot and fun, but we should favor simplicity first. In this case, if there wasn't that BITSTRING interference explained by ygrek, a simple solution would to pass `of_int` and `succ`  as parameters of the `build_data` function. I find it disturbing that you offer three solutions with much boilerplate, but not this one.

Comment: @gasche: yes, passing the of_int and succ functions in as params would probably be the easiest... except for the issue explained by ygrek.  Still, it's interesting to see the first-class module solution.